# Python3 Dictionary - Python not finding a key that definitely exists

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

This seemingly basic dictionary example below is not working as intended, and I'm in need of a sanity check. 
I expect the variable "my_name" to contain "NetOpsTest_1A" once I pull it from the dictionary called tag_dict. However it is behaving like it can't find the key "Name". 
Below is exactly how I typed it in the Python3 shell. 
Thanks

```
Python 3.6.8 (default, Apr 25 2019, 21:02:35)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> tag_dict = {'Value': 'NetOpsTest_1A', 'Key': 'Name'}
>>> print(type(tag_dict))
<class 'dict'>
>>> my_name = tag_dict.get("Name", "")
>>> print(my_name)

>>>
```

Comment: 'Name' is a value not a key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserting into a dictionary, the first value is always the key, and 2nd value is always the value. You don't want to use 'Key' and 'Value'.

```
$ python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 21:07:45)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> tag_dict = { 'Name': 'NetOpsTest_1A' }
>>> print(type(tag_dict))
<class 'dict'>
>>> my_name = tag_dict.get("Name", "")
>>> print(my_name)
NetOpsTest_1A
>>>
```

Comment: Reversing the key and value positions has no effect.

`>>> tag_dict = {'key': 'Name', 'Value': 'NetOpsTest_1A'}
>>> my_name = tag_dict.get("Name", "Cant' Find it")
>>> print(my_name)
Cant' Find it
>>>`

Comment: Thanks, I just re-read your answer and understand it now.